# Dockerfile COPY excluding previous copied folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We want to split the docker layer of our ONE source folder into TWO. Is this possible?

From this

```
COPY . .
```

To this

```
COPY ./static .     #big folder
COPY .[^static] .   #the rest of the code
```

Context: We have a 60MB source folder that has 58MB of static files (images) that almost never change. If we could create a layer with this big folder first, it would be cached by docker and would result in faster builds and smaller pushs and pulls.

I can't (or wouldn't like) to move this static folder outside of the source folder. It would break the commom archetype of the
project which, I think, wouldn't compensate the benefits.

Comment: I recommend separating folders is a better idea since Docker can cache the layers and does the building process faster

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to refactor your tree as follow:

1. data/dynamic
2. data/static

The update your docker file as follow:

```
COPY data/static .
COPY data/dynamic .
```

So the static subfolder will be cached as you expect.

Comment: This is one way of doing it. But the drawback is that I would have to change the structure of the project itself to suit this. I think this wouldn't compansate the benefit. I was looking for a transparent solution that could copy an inner folder first, than copy the rest (without that previous folder)